# scp or rsync multiple files from source server to another servers

Tags: server, bash, rsync, nfs, scp

Since my `nfs` is a `win` type of server, it can't contain `:`. I want to copy multiple files from source server to the `nfs` directory on another server and rename them at the same time.

The script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

in_files="node1:~/experiment/wrfout_d01_2012-12-01*"
###########################################################
# the files look like wrfout_d01_2012-12-01_00:00:00
# wrfout_d01_2012-12-01_06:00:00
# wrfout_d01_2012-12-01_12:00:00
# wrfout_d01_2012-12-01_18:00:00
###################################
for fn in $in_files;do
  echo $fn
  newfn=$(basename "$fn")
  echo 'apply basename :'
  echo $newfn
  scp -r "$fn"  "./${newfn//:/_}"
  echo 'next:'
done
```

After run this script, it reports

```
node1:~/experiment/wrfout_d01_2012-12-01*
apply basename :
wrfout_d01_2012-12-01_12_00_00
./wrfout_d01_2012-12-01*: File name too long
./wrfout_d01_2012-12-01*: File name too long
./wrfout_d01_2012-12-01*: File name too long
./wrfout_d01_2012-12-01*: File name too long
next:
```

But it seems that if I apply the script to only one file, it is OK,(i.e. change the `in_files` to a certain file),for example:

```
node1:~/experiment/wrfout_d01_2012-12-01_00:00:00
apply basename :
wrfout_d01_2012-12-01_00:00:00
wrfout_d01_2012-12-01_00:00:00        100%   71MB  70.5MB/s   00:00    
next:
```

1.So how should I do to let it work for multiple files?

2.By the way it seems `rsync` can also do this part, which one is faster or preferred.

Comment: Rsync is always preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your target files are on another system. Therefore, your glob (`node1:~/experiment/wrfout_d01_2012-12-01*`) is never expanded. You can see this right there in the output you posted. The first line of output comes from `echo $fn` and it prints this:

```
node1:~/experiment/wrfout_d01_2012-12-01*
```

You are not iterating over ever file matching that glob, you are only processing the glob itself as a string. So, instead of attempting to list files that you don't yet have access to (you need to open the ssh connection to see the list of files), just bring everything over and rename locally:

```
#!/bin/bash

rsync -v node1:"~/experiment/wrfout_d01_2012-12-01*" .
rename 's/:/_/g' wrfout_d01_2012-12-01*
```

---

Alternatively, **assuming your file names don't contain newline characters**, you can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

in_files=($(ssh node1 'ls ~/experiment/wrfout_d01_2012-12-01*') )
for fn in "${in_files[@]}";do
  newfn=$(basename "$fn")
  rsync node1:"$fn"  "${newfn//:/_}"
done
```

Comment: But, in this `nfs` directory, it would report  `Input/output error` if the filename contain `:`. That is why I want to rename it at the same time of copy. It is noted that if the `in_files` is only a filename, it works. So the problem may become that can we obtain a list of filenames from source server?

Comment: @AllenZhang then you need to ssh to node1, get the files and then copy. See updated answer.